# NextJS beta how to receive data from client component on server component

Tags: next.js

I'm working on Next 13.3.1 and I think I don't understand something in server/client components

I'm fetching intial data on my page.tsx file and also render some client components.
Those client components are part of my filtering system. Now I want to receive some data from that client components on my parent server component so I can receive new data with applied filters.

So in general my initial fetch url is like localhost/api/someendpoint
after I handle something on my client component I want to fetch it again but with url like localhost/api/someendpoint?filters=somefilter

I tried to pass a props to parent component like it's possible on client components, just setting props.onData() on my child component and handling it on my parent component but I was getting error that I can't use functions as it's server component.

I also tried wrapping my server component with client component but then fetch function runs also on client so it's not safe as it may reveal my api token and I think it's losing a point of having server components if i mark everything with "use client"